# Source not found!

Tags: java, android, eclipse, events, onclick

I'm trying to write an application that opens another window when a button is selected here is what I have so far:

```
public class AndroidAlarm extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button codesBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    codesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View argo) {
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidAlarm.this, Codes.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

   }
}
```

This is what I have in my default class, the activity I'm trying to start is a class called Codes:

```
public class Codes extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.codes);
    }
}
```

It will have functionality but right now I'm just trying to open it.  Codes.java (above) is connected to a layout called codes.xml.

My manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.affirma.androidalarm"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity class =".AndroidAlarm" android:name = ".AndroidAlarm"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity class = ".Codes" android:name = ".Codes" android:label="Codes">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I run the program, it will start then crash saying it ended abruptly.  When I debug, it breaks at this line found in AndroidAlarm.java:

```
codesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

It says that the Source is not found.  something about "activitythread.preformlauncher..."  Anyways I don't know why this is happening any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the complete stacktrace of the error message.  Use logcat: `adb logcat` or the DDMS perspective in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is because it is trying to find the id of  "imagebutton1" from R.java files which is in the R.layout.main. so please make sure you have imagebutton1 has been initialized properly and R.java contains the id of the same.

Comment: in my R.java file there is he line:  `public static final int imagebutton1=0x7f070001;`  So i know its being properly initialized.  Even when i put my cursor over imagebutton1 in `Button codesBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);` it displays the memory address of the button.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your imagebutton1 is in the R.layout.main? i tried your code and it's working fine